# Is it sufficient to say a (nonempty) set is closed if it contains both its greatest lower, and least upper bound?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

This makes sense intuitively, but I don't have a theorem anywhere that says it outright.

The overall proof I'm working on is $C$ is a closed non-empty subset of $\Bbb R$ iff the distance from $x$ to $C$ is greater than $0$ for all $x$ in $C$ complement.

Comment: On $\mathbb R$ you need the set to be connected for the property to be true.

Answer (score 3):

Think about the set in $\mathbb{R}$ of $[-1,0)\cup (0,1]$.

Comment: That's a really good point... thanks

Comment: $C$ must contain _all_ its limit points and you are including only two, the glb and lub.  I'd argue this statement by contradiction.

Comment: Ok I think I got a decent proof, thanks so much